# Why do so many organizations collect first and last name on the sign up page?

Tags: forms, registration, personalisation

Can anyone explain to me, why so many organizations collect your first and last name (rather than just your full name) on the sign up page?

Comment: Pretty simple answer: Companies like user data--specifically, who you are.

Comment: I think he means why two fields instead of a single "Name" field. I've wondered this as well. I don't remember the last time it was vital to sort by last name, nor have I ever cared how many "Smiths" there were.

Comment: As worded, this question is not ultimately seeking a UX-centric solution. The answer is, as already pointed out, the simple collection of user data.

Comment: @NathanRabe - that possibility does not seem apparent based on the wording of the question. There is no indication Pavel is asking about the number of fields, versus just collecting the data. If that is indeed what he is asking, I recall the question already being asked in the past.

Comment: @ Pavel - if your question is simply limited to why organizations ask for users name then this forum is not the best place for it. If you're asking how best to get users to submit this information, one field or two - or even when would it be best to ask - then the question would be more suited for this site.

Comment: Because the alternative would be likely to be asking for the full name and what do you *actually want* to be called - ref: [Merging firstname/last name into one field](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/merging-firstname-last-name-into-one-field). Some notable examples of those that only ask for full name are Amazon, Twitter, Quora, Vimeo, SourceForge, and um... nope that's all I know of. As a sidenote, I've found that something of the order of 50% of 'popular' websites don't ask for your name at all.

Comment: Also of interest: [Can I reformat personal names obtained from a single form field?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37544/can-i-reformat-personal-names-obtained-from-a-single-form-field).

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I hear your comment, but there is also a common UX-driven reason for collecting first/last names for the sake of presenting a more personalized interface.  I've debated this exact issue before for a social website (we wanted to be able to personalize using first names), and we decided to go with the extra field on signup knowing that it was more up-front friction.

Answer (score 6):

### Because it's helpful to know the first name and the last name, rather than just the full name

---

#### Why it can't be done automatically

- Without asking, a site cannot tell the difference between the following names:

  [image]

#### Why it matters

Sites often want to be able to communicate with customers using different styles, where first and last names are more effective than full names.

For example:

- Dear Mr. Morgan, we are pleased to offer you the position of Chief Executive of our Too Big To Fail bank.
- Hi John, it was great seeing you at our sample sale on Saturday. We hope you will return as a customer for future events.
- Welcome back, John!

Being able to use a customer's first or last name can feel more polite or personalized than using a full name:

- <strike>Dear James Pierpont Morgan</strike>, we are pleased to offer....
- <strike>Hi James Pierpont Morgan</strike>, it was great seeing you...
- <strike>Welcome back, James Pierpont Morgan!</strike>

Comment: One more reason: you can generate full name from first name + last name, but not vice versa.

Comment: One thing to be aware of: it's not safe to assume the last name is the family name (i.e., Mr X).

Answer (score 2):

Because it is impossible to split later in many cases without input from the user.  Eg. when people give 3 words, you don't know if it is a double barreled last name or first name (or if they have included a middle name).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is how first and last names are handled in different cultures. One reason why it's better to only have one field for full name instead of separate fields for first name and last name.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its just sheer laziness by the GUI creation teams. Just following the legacy template. Companies should start having one field for name. With Diverse cultures having unique naming conventions - some have only one name, some have even five. Why is IT still stuck with the First and last name convention. In my opinion Its absurd in todays word and the software developers should have one field for name. Making everyone's life easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).